# html/templates - Replacing newlines with <br>

Tags: html, templates, go

I'm loading a text file that has newlines in it, and pass it to `html/templates`.

Substituting the `\n` with `<br>` in the loaded string, they are escaped by the template to html `&lt;br&gt;` and displayed in the browser, instead of causing a line return.

How can I change this behavior without switching to `text/templates` (which doesn't have XSS protection)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems you could run template.HTMLEscape() on your text first to sanitize it, then do the \n to 
 substitution that you trust, then use that as pre-escaped and trusted template data.

Update:  Expanding on Kocka's example, this is what I had in mind:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const page = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>{{.}}</p>
  </body>
</html>`

const text = `first line
<script>dangerous</script>
last line`

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("page").Parse(page))
    safe := template.HTMLEscapeString(text)
    safe = strings.Replace(safe, "\n", "<br>", -1)
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, template.HTML(safe)) // template.HTML encapsulates a known safe HTML document fragment.
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/JiH0uD5Zh2

Output is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>first line<br>&lt;script&gt;dangerous&lt;/script&gt;<br>last line</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And text rendered in the browser is

```
first line
<script>dangerous</script>
last line
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure where you're substituting `\n` for `<br>` but if it's in go, you can cast the string as `template.HTML` so it's not escaped.

See: http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#HTML

If it's in a template, there should be a pipeline available, `{{. | html}}`

Comment: I can't cast it to `template.HTML` because my string isn't safe.
Could you elaborate the pileline trick? Thanks a lot

Comment: if the string isn't safe then the pipeline isn't going to help either. Try splitting the string on `"\n"` and passing the resulting slice into the template. Use `range` to print the string and insert `<br>`. For example:

`Arr := strings.Split(myString, "\n")` in the go code, and

`{{range Arr}}{{.}}<br>{{end}}` in the template.

Comment: @dskinner, I know it's late, but you should write yours out as a full response. It's a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

const page = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>{{.}}</p>
  </body>
</html>`

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("page").Parse(page))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, template.HTML("<br>"))
}
```

[Try it out!](http://play.golang.org/p/wngIYuZuN2)

Comment: This is actually the right track --- but saw, that the input is not save, which requires more processing, as correctly done in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer can easily be turned into a custom template function:

```golang
func replaceNewline(s string) template.HTML {
    return template.HTML(strings.Replace(template.HTMLEscapeString(s), "\n", "<br>", -1))
}
```

Add it with [`func (*Template) Funcs`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Funcs)

**Example**

```golang
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

const page = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>{{. | replaceNewline}}</p>
  </body>
</html>`

const text = `first line
<script>dangerous</script>
last line`

func main() {
    t := template.Must(template.New("page").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        "replaceNewline": func(s string) template.HTML {
            return template.HTML(strings.Replace(template.HTMLEscapeString(s), "\n", "<br>", -1))
        },
    }).Parse(page))
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, text)
}
```

**Output**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>first line<br>&lt;script&gt;dangerous&lt;/script&gt;<br>last line</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FZJfjYKWKNv)

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary to pass your entire template as an unsafe template (and this is bad practice).

You should pass a map to your template, and only explicitly 'unsafe' the elements you want to use as such, eg.

```
package main

import "bytes"
import "fmt"
import "html/template"
import "strings"

var input = `
  {{ define "LAYOUT" }}
    <html>
      <body>
        {{ template "CONTENT" . }}
      </body>
    </html>
  {{ end }}

  {{ define "CONTENT" }}
    Unsafe content: {{ .Unsafe }}
    Newlines converted to <br/> follow:
    {{ .Normal }}
  {{ end }}

  {{ template "LAYOUT" . }}
`

var other = `
  Hello
  World
  Again
`

var other2 = `
  <script>alert("Owned!");</script>
`

func main() {

    var t, err = template.New("sample").Parse(input)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var fixed = strings.Replace(other, "\n", "\n<br/>", -1)
    var model = map[string]interface{}{
        "Normal": template.HTML(fixed),
        "Unsafe": other2,
    }

    var out bytes.Buffer
    t.Execute(&out, model) # <--- !! Notice the model is NOT an HTML type.

    var raw = out.String()
    fmt.Printf("%s", raw)
}
```

Yields:

> ```
> Unsafe content:    &lt;script&gt;alert(&#34;Owned!&#34;);&lt;/script&gt;
>
> Newlines converted to <br/> follow:
>  <br/>  Hello 
>  <br/>  World 
>  <br/>  Again 
>  <br/>
>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: While the idea is right, the implementation is wrong: marking a string as "safe" by wrapping it in `template.HTML(...)` disables all other escaping, so e.g. any single-line `<script>` elements in `other` would be passed through to the output verbatim. You need to add more escaping before marking `fixed` as safe, e.g. by using `template.HTMLEscape()` before substituting the newlines.